# insert html code from a form helper in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a code something like this:

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <%= label_tag 'customer_email', 'Customer Email' %>
   <div class="input">
     <%= text_field_tag 'customer_email', nil, :class => 'xlarge' %>                              
    </div>
  </div><!-- /customer_email -->
```

I would like to insert this code into my view dynamically using a form helper. So in my view I just have to call the method which will insert the following block with just field_tag name changes which I can store in a list of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define a method in your application_helper.rb somthing like:

```
def formatted_text_field(name, value = nil, options ={})
  "<div class='clearfix'>" +
    label_tag(name) +
    "<div class='input'>" +
      text_field_tag(name, value, :class => 'xlarge') +
    "</div>" +
  "</div>"
end
```

you can then call `<%= formatted_text_field('customer_email', nil) %>` from any view.

And you can also store the string in a variable in the helper method and instead return `output.html_safe`.

Comment: Good point. You can also store the string in a variable in the helper method and instead return `output.html_safe`

Answer (score 0):

Dump the code in a partial and use variable names as placeholders for field attributes.  When rendering the partial, populate variables with whatever field names you want to use.
(Am on a mobile device right now, will add an example later, if you want)